# I try to use the changeNotifierProvider but it is not working for me

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I have the following code in my project, what I'm trying to do is initialize the 'assignacionHorarioFormProvider' provider to later use it in the 'ChangeNotifierProvider', but somehow the widget tree is not updated under it when there are changes in the provider , which is what I'm doing wrong. (this code is not in the main of the project, since the provider should only influence the specific component where it is being used).
And here is my code

```
import 'package:dropdown_search/dropdown_search.dart';
import 'package:escamet_erp_app/interfaces/layouts/splash/global_data.dart';
import 'package:escamet_erp_app/interfaces/views/asistencias/asignacion_horario/asignacion_horario_form_provider.dart';
import 'package:escamet_erp_app/interfaces/views/asistencias/asignacion_horario/widgets_asignacion_horario/calendario_por_mes_y_year.dart';
import 'package:escamet_erp_app/interfaces/views/asistencias/asignacion_horario/widgets_asignacion_horario/column_table_calendario_asignacion_horario.dart';
import 'package:escamet_erp_app/interfaces/views/asistencias/asignacion_horario/widgets_asignacion_horario/data_grid_source_calendario.dart';
import 'package:escamet_erp_app/interfaces/views/usuarios/usuario_imports_view.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_datagrid/datagrid.dart';

class AsignacionHorarioView extends StatefulWidget {
  const AsignacionHorarioView({Key? key, this.nombreUsuario = '', this.usuarioId = '', this.fecha}) : super(key: key);
  final String? nombreUsuario;
  final String? usuarioId;
  final DateTime? fecha;

  @override
  State<AsignacionHorarioView> createState() => _AsignacionHorarioViewState();
}

class _AsignacionHorarioViewState extends State<AsignacionHorarioView> {
  // final aasignacionHorarioService = AsignacionHorarioService();
  // late AsignacionHorarioFormProvider asignacionHorarioFormProvider = AsignacionHorarioFormProvider();
  late AsignacionHorarioFormProvider asignacionHorarioFormProvider;
  final tipoJornadaService = TipoJornadaService();
  bool calendarioGenerado = false;
  final DataGridController _dataGridController = DataGridController();
  late Stream streamControllerJornadas;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    asignacionHorarioFormProvider = AsignacionHorarioFormProvider();
    asignacionHorarioFormProvider.obtenerFechasInicial(widget.fecha);
    print('ya paso por aca');
    // asignacionHorarioFormProvider.addListener(calendarioListener);
    asignacionHorarioFormProvider.apiCallTipoJornada = tipoJornadaService.getActivos;
    asignacionHorarioFormProvider.refrescarDropDownTipoJornada();
    streamControllerJornadas = tipoJornadaService.tipoJornadaDropdownStream;

    asignacionHorarioFormProvider.usuarioId =
        widget.usuarioId! != '' ? widget.usuarioId! : asignacionHorarioFormProvider.usuarioId;
    asignacionHorarioFormProvider.usuarioNombre =
        widget.nombreUsuario! != '' ? widget.nombreUsuario! : asignacionHorarioFormProvider.usuarioNombre;
  }

  // void calendarioListener() {
  //   if (asignacionHorarioFormProvider.semanasMesActual.isEmpty) {
  //     calendarioGenerado = false;
  //   } else {
  //     calendarioGenerado = true;
  //     setState(() {});
  //   }
  // }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => asignacionHorarioFormProvider,
      child: ListView(children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              // Row(
              //   children: [
              //     Text.rich(TextSpan(
              //         text: 'Usuario ',
              //         children: [
              //           TextSpan(
              //               text: asignacionHorarioFormProvider.usuarioNombre,
              //               style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
              //         ],
              //         style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.black54, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600))),
              //   ],
              // ),
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  selectJornada(),
                  const SizedBox(width: 10),
                  Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: Card(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          child: calendarioMes(),
                        ),
                      ))
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }

}
```

And this is the code of the provider

```
import 'package:escamet_erp_app/helpers/formatear_fecha.dart';
import 'package:escamet_erp_app/interfaces/views/asistencias/asignacion_horario/asignacion_horario_service.dart';
import 'package:escamet_erp_app/interfaces/views/asistencias/asignacion_horario/widgets_asignacion_horario/asignacion_dia_especifico_dialog.dart';
import 'package:escamet_erp_app/interfaces/views/configuraciones/indexOf/services.dart';
import 'package:escamet_erp_app/services/borradores/borrador_service.dart';
import 'package:escamet_erp_app/settings/dialogs/custom_dialogs.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class AsignacionHorarioFormProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  AsignacionHorarioService asignacionHorarioService = AsignacionHorarioService();

  bool resetForm = false;
  bool hayDatos = false;

  bool isEditing = false;
  String _idEditing = '';
  String _idBorrador = '';

  String usuarioId = '6299083fc0e636cb2ed6e4f9';
  String usuarioNombre = 'Christian Eduardo Godoy Villalobos';
  String fechaInicioContrato = '01/04/2022';
  String fechaTerminoContrato = '30/12/2022';

  late String fechaActualFormateada;
  late String fechaActualEscrita;
  late String mesEscrito;
  late int anio;
  late int semanaDelAnio;
  late int ultimoDiaMesAnterior;
  late int ultimoDiaMesActual;
  // guardar en que indice de la semana cae el primer dia del mes ej: Jueves seria el 3 (comienza en 0)
  late int indiceDelPrimerDia;
  // guardar en que indice de la semana cae el ultimo dia del mes ej: Jueves seria el 3 (comienza en 0)
  late int indiceDelUltimoDia;
  DateTime fechaActual = DateTime.now();

  // Guardar las semanas del mes actual
  List<dynamic> semanasMesActual = [];

  String nombreTipoJornada = '';
  String idTipoJornada = '';
  String tipoHorario = '';
  // para ver si es rotativo o fijo (rotativo = true || fijo = false)
  bool tipoHorarioBool = false;

  String nombreHorarioSelected = '';
  String idHorarioSelected = '';

  List horarios = [];
  List asignacionHorarioUsuario = [];

  setNuevaAsignacionHorario(int numeroSemana, int year, BuildContext context) async {
    dynamic horario = await getHorarioPorCalendario(numeroSemana, year);

    if (horario != -1) {
      // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
      bool respuestaEdicion = await CustomDialogs.showQuestionDialog(context, '¿Desea editar la asignacion horaria?',
          'Esta semana ya posee una asignacion horaria, en caso de confirmar, la asignacion horaria sera editada por la seleccionada.');
      if (!respuestaEdicion) return;
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> json = {
      'rotativo': tipoHorarioBool,
      'semana': numeroSemana,
      'year': year,
      'horario': idHorarioSelected
    };
    dynamic nuevaData = await asignacionHorarioService.put(json, usuarioId);

    asignacionHorarioUsuario = nuevaData['lista_horarios'];
    notifyListeners();
  }

  // funcion que recimbe el numero de la semana en el año y tambien el año al que corresponde ese numero de la semana
  /// se busca en la variable [asignacionHorarioUsuario] que posee todas las asignaciones de horario
  /// del usuario seleccionado para buscar si durante la semana y el año de los parametros que se estan
  /// enviando por esta funcion existe alguna asignacion horaria. en el cual retorna un `1` si
  /// encuentra un asignacion y un `-1` en el caso contrario.
  getHorarioPorCalendario(int numeroSemana, int year) {
    final result =
        asignacionHorarioUsuario.indexWhere((element) => element['year'] == year && element['semana'] == numeroSemana);

    // en caso de que exista un horario rotativo en la fecha recibida devolver inmediatamente esa asignacion horaria
    if (result != -1) return result;

    // antes de la fecha de inicio de contrato no debe existir asignacion horaria
    if (fechaInicioContrato.isNotEmpty) {
      List fechaInicioSplit = fechaInicioContrato.split('/');
      DateTime fechaInicio =
          DateTime.parse(fechaInicioSplit[2] + '-' + fechaInicioSplit[1] + '-' + fechaInicioSplit[0]);
      int semanaInicioContrato = FormatearFecha().weekNumber(fechaInicio);
      if (fechaInicio.year > year || (fechaInicio.year == year && semanaInicioContrato > numeroSemana)) {
        return -1;
      }
    }

    // verificar si el usuario posee la fecha de termino de contrato y ademas tenga un contrato fijo
    // las asignaciones horaria termine en esa misma fecha
    if (fechaTerminoContrato.isNotEmpty) {
      List fechaTerminoSplit = fechaTerminoContrato.split('/');
      DateTime fechaTermino =
          DateTime.parse(fechaTerminoSplit[2] + '-' + fechaTerminoSplit[1] + '-' + fechaTerminoSplit[0]);
      int semanaTerminoContrato = FormatearFecha().weekNumber(fechaTermino);
      if (fechaTermino.year < year || (fechaTermino.year == year && semanaTerminoContrato < numeroSemana)) {
        return -1;
      }
    }

    /// asignacion horaria fija con un `hasta` agregado
    final resultConHasta = asignacionHorarioUsuario.indexWhere((element) => ((element['hasta_semana'] != null &&
            element['hasta_year'] != null) &&
        FormatearFecha()
            .compararFechaAsignacionHoraria(element['hasta_year'], element['hasta_semana'], '$numeroSemana-$year') &&
        (element['year'] > year || (element['year'] == year && element['semana'] <= numeroSemana))));
    if (resultConHasta != -1) return resultConHasta;

    /// asignacion horario fija sin un `hasta` agregado
    final resultadoSinHasta = asignacionHorarioUsuario.indexWhere((element) =>
        (year > element['year']) ||
        (element['year'] == year && element['semana'] <= numeroSemana) &&
            element['hasta_semana'] == null &&
            element['hasta_year'] == null);
    if (resultadoSinHasta != -1) return resultadoSinHasta;

    // si no encuentra ningun horario pues no devuelve indice del horario
    return -1;
  }

  List<Widget> getMarcacionesDelDia(Map<String, dynamic> horario, int indiceDia, bool diaMesActual) {
    Map<String, dynamic> marcaciones = {
      'entrada': '',
      'colacion:': '',
      'fin_colacion': '',
      'salida': '',
      'entrada_2': '',
      'colacion_2': '',
      'fin_colacion_2': '',
      'salida_2': ''
    };
    List<String> mDelDia;
    switch (indiceDia) {
      //LUNES
      case 0:
        mDelDia = horario['horario']['lunes'].split(';');
        break;
      // MARTES
      case 1:
        mDelDia = horario['horario']['martes'].split(';');
        break;
      // MIERCOLES
      case 2:
        mDelDia = horario['horario']['miercoles'].split(';');
        break;
      // JUEVES
      case 3:
        mDelDia = horario['horario']['jueves'].split(';');
        break;
      // VIERNES
      case 4:
        mDelDia = horario['horario']['viernes'].split(';');
        break;
      // SABADO
      case 5:
        mDelDia = horario['horario']['sabado'].split(';');
        break;
      // DOMINGO
      case 6:
        mDelDia = horario['horario']['domingo'].split(';');
        break;
      default:
        mDelDia = [];
    }

    if (mDelDia.length > 1) {
      marcaciones['entrada'] = FormatearFecha().minutosHaciaHoraHorarioAsignado(int.parse(mDelDia[0]));
      marcaciones['colacion'] = FormatearFecha().minutosHaciaHoraHorarioAsignado(int.parse(mDelDia[1]));
      marcaciones['fin_colacion'] = FormatearFecha().minutosHaciaHoraHorarioAsignado(int.parse(mDelDia[2]));
      marcaciones['salida'] = FormatearFecha().minutosHaciaHoraHorarioAsignado(int.parse(mDelDia[3]));
    }
    if (mDelDia.length > 4) {
      marcaciones['entrada_2'] = FormatearFecha().minutosHaciaHoraHorarioAsignado(int.parse(mDelDia[4]));
      marcaciones['colacion_2'] = FormatearFecha().minutosHaciaHoraHorarioAsignado(int.parse(mDelDia[5]));
      marcaciones['fin_colacion_2'] = FormatearFecha().minutosHaciaHoraHorarioAsignado(int.parse(mDelDia[6]));
      marcaciones['salida_2'] = FormatearFecha().minutosHaciaHoraHorarioAsignado(int.parse(mDelDia[7]));
    }

    if (mDelDia.length <= 1) {
      return [
        Text(
          'Dia Libre',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            color: diaMesActual ? Colors.black : Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
          ),
        )
      ];
    }
    if (mDelDia.isNotEmpty && mDelDia.length <= 4) {
      TextStyle textWeight400 = const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400);
      TextStyle textWeight600 =
          TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, color: diaMesActual ? Colors.black : Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5));

      return [
        Text.rich(
          TextSpan(
            text: 'Ent. ',
            children: [
              TextSpan(
                text: marcaciones['entrada'],
                style: textWeight400,
              )
            ],
            style: textWeight600,
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 5),
        Text.rich(
          TextSpan(
            text: 'Sal. ',
            children: [
              TextSpan(
                text: marcaciones['salida'],
                style: textWeight400,
              )
            ],
            style: textWeight600,
          ),
        ),
      ];
    } else {
      TextStyle textBold400Size12 = const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, fontSize: 14);
      TextStyle textBold600Size12 = TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
          fontSize: 12,
          color: diaMesActual ? Colors.black : Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5));

      return [
        Text.rich(
          TextSpan(
              text: 'Ent. ',
              children: [TextSpan(text: marcaciones['entrada'], style: textBold400Size12)],
              style: textBold600Size12),
        ),
        Text.rich(
          TextSpan(
              text: 'Sal. ',
              children: [TextSpan(text: marcaciones['salida'], style: textBold400Size12)],
              style: textBold600Size12),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
            height: 3,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
              child: Divider(
                thickness: 2,
                color: Colors.black54,
              ),
            )),
        Text.rich(
          TextSpan(
              text: 'Ent.2 ',
              children: [TextSpan(text: marcaciones['entrada_2'], style: textBold400Size12)],
              style: textBold600Size12),
        ),
        Text.rich(
          TextSpan(
              text: 'Sal.2 ',
              children: [TextSpan(text: marcaciones['salida_2'], style: textBold400Size12)],
              style: textBold600Size12),
        ),
      ];
    }
  }

  setNuevoTipoJornada(String nombre, String id, String tipo) async {
    horarios = [];
    nombreHorarioSelected = '';
    idHorarioSelected = '';
    nombreTipoJornada = nombre;
    idTipoJornada = id;
    tipoHorario = tipo;
    tipoHorarioBool = tipo == 'Rotativo' ? true : false;
    horarios = await HorarioService().getPorTipoJornada(id);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  setNuevoHorario(String id, String nombre) {
    idHorarioSelected = idHorarioSelected != id ? id : '';
    nombreHorarioSelected = nombreHorarioSelected != nombre ? nombre : '';
    notifyListeners();
  }

  // *******************  FECHAS   ***************************
  void obtenerFechasInicial(DateTime? fecha) async {
    if (fecha != null) {
      fechaActual = fecha;
    }
    semanasMesActual.clear();
    // ignore: prefer_if_null_operators
    fechaActualFormateada =
        // ignore: prefer_if_null_operators
        FormatearFecha().formatearFecha(fecha == null ? DateTime.now() : fecha);
    fechaActualEscrita = FormatearFecha().fechaAfechaEscrita(fechaActualFormateada);
    mesEscrito = FormatearFecha().obtenerMesEscrito(fechaActualFormateada);
    anio = int.parse(FormatearFecha().obtenerAnio(fechaActualFormateada));
    semanaDelAnio = FormatearFecha().weekNumber(fechaActual);
    await getUltimoDiaMesAnterior();
    await getUltimoDiaMesActual();
    await getIndicePrimerDia();
    await getIndiceUltimoDia();
    await generarSemanasMesActual();

    dynamic horario = await asignacionHorarioService.porUsuario(usuarioId);

    asignacionHorarioUsuario = horario['lista_horarios'];
    notifyListeners();
  }

  // sumar un mes en el calendario
  void sumarUnMes(BuildContext context) async {
    fechaActual = DateTime(fechaActual.year, fechaActual.month + 1, 1);
    await getFechasEnBaseFechaActual();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  // restar un mes al calendario
  void restarUnMes(BuildContext context) async {
    fechaActual = DateTime(fechaActual.year, fechaActual.month - 1, 1);
    await getFechasEnBaseFechaActual();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  // sumar un año al calendario
  void sumarUnAnio(BuildContext context) async {
    fechaActual = DateTime(fechaActual.year + 1, fechaActual.month, 1);
    await getFechasEnBaseFechaActual();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  // restar un año al calendario
  void restarUnAnio(BuildContext context) async {
    fechaActual = DateTime(fechaActual.year - 1, fechaActual.month, 1);
    await getFechasEnBaseFechaActual();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  /// Obtener la `fechaActualFormateada`, `fechaActualEscrita`, `mesEscrito`, `anio`, `semanaDelAnio` en base
  /// a la fecha indicada en `fechaActual` con el formato de DateTime
  getFechasEnBaseFechaActual() async {
    fechaActualFormateada = FormatearFecha().formatearFecha(fechaActual);
    fechaActualEscrita = FormatearFecha().fechaAfechaEscrita(fechaActualFormateada);
    mesEscrito = FormatearFecha().obtenerMesEscrito(fechaActualFormateada);
    anio = int.parse(FormatearFecha().obtenerAnio(fechaActualFormateada));
    semanaDelAnio = FormatearFecha().weekNumber(fechaActual);
    await getUltimoDiaMesAnterior();
    await getUltimoDiaMesActual();
    await getIndicePrimerDia();
    await getIndiceUltimoDia();
    await generarSemanasMesActual();

    notifyListeners();
  }

  // generar array con las semanas del mes que esta mostrando en el calendario
  // aqui se generan las semanas y se indica el numero de la semana cual es la primera y cual es la ultima
  Future generarSemanasMesActual() async {
    semanasMesActual.clear();
    int primeraSemana = FormatearFecha().weekNumber(DateTime(fechaActual.year, fechaActual.month, 1));
    int ultimaSemana = FormatearFecha().weekNumber(DateTime(fechaActual.year, fechaActual.month + 1, 0));
    for (int semana = primeraSemana == 52 || primeraSemana == 53 ? 0 : primeraSemana;
        semana <= (ultimaSemana == 1 ? 53 : ultimaSemana);
        semana++) {
      semanasMesActual.add({
        'year': anio,
        'semana': primeraSemana == 52 && semana == 0
            ? primeraSemana
            : semana == 53 && (ultimaSemana != 53 && primeraSemana != 53)
                ? 1
                : semana != 0
                    ? semana
                    : primeraSemana,
        'primera_semana': false,
        'ultima_semana': false,
        'dias': []
      });
    }
    semanasMesActual[0]['primera_semana'] = true;
    semanasMesActual[semanasMesActual.length - 1]['ultima_semana'] = true;

    int dia = 0;
    semanasMesActual.map((semana) {
      // en estos dos ifs se arreglan los años de las semanas
      // en el de dicimebre si el mes lo es y la semana es 1 el año es el anterior al registrado anteriormente
      if (mesEscrito == 'Diciembre' && semana['semana'] == 1) {
        semana['year'] = semana['year'] + 1;
      }
      // si el mes es enero y la semana es 52 o 53 se le debe de sumar un año al registrado anteriormente
      if (mesEscrito == 'Enero' && (semana['semana'] == 52 || semana['semana'] == 53)) {
        semana['year'] = semana['year'] - 1;
      }
      int diasEnSemana = 1;
      // verifica si es la primera semana del mes
      if (semana['primera_semana']) {
        // verifica si el primer dia de la semana es distinto a lunes
        if (indiceDelPrimerDia > 0) {
          // obtiene el primer dia de la semana que por lo general es el mes anterior
          dia = ultimoDiaMesAnterior - indiceDelPrimerDia + 1;
        } else {
          dia = 1;
        }
        for (diasEnSemana; diasEnSemana <= 7; diasEnSemana++) {
          // los dias pasaron al mes actual
          if (dia != ultimoDiaMesAnterior) {
            semana['dias'].add({'numero_dia': dia, 'mes_actual': dia > 7 ? false : true});
          } else {
            semana['dias'].add({'numero_dia': dia, 'mes_actual': false});
            dia = 0;
          }
          dia++;
        }
      }
      // verifica si es la ultima semana que aparece en el calendario y tambien si tiene dias del mes
      // actual dentro de esa semana
      if (semana['ultima_semana']) {
        for (diasEnSemana; diasEnSemana <= 7; diasEnSemana++) {
          if (dia > ultimoDiaMesActual) {
            dia = 1;
            semana['dias'].add({'numero_dia': dia, 'mes_actual': false});
          } else {
            semana['dias'].add({'numero_dia': dia, 'mes_actual': dia >= 7 ? true : false});
          }
          dia++;
        }
      }

      // si la semana no es la ultima ni la primera
      if (!semana['ultima_semana'] && !semana['primera_semana']) {
        for (diasEnSemana; diasEnSemana <= 7; diasEnSemana++) {
          if (dia > ultimoDiaMesActual) {
            dia = 1;
            semana['dias'].add({'numero_dia': dia, 'mes_actual': false});
          } else {
            semana['dias'].add({'numero_dia': dia, 'mes_actual': dia <= ultimoDiaMesActual ? true : false});
          }
          dia++;
        }
      }
    }).toList();
  }

  getUltimoDiaMesAnterior() {
    DateTime ultimoDia = DateTime(fechaActual.year, fechaActual.month, 0);
    ultimoDiaMesAnterior = ultimoDia.day;
  }

  getUltimoDiaMesActual() {
    DateTime ultimoDia = DateTime(fechaActual.year, fechaActual.month + 1, 0);
    ultimoDiaMesActual = ultimoDia.day;
  }

  getIndicePrimerDia() {
    String primerDia = DateFormat('EEEE').format(DateTime(fechaActual.year, fechaActual.month, 1));
    indiceDelPrimerDia = FormatearFecha().obtenerIndiceDelDiaEnLaSemana(primerDia);
    getUltimoDiaMesAnterior();
  }

  getIndiceUltimoDia() {
    String ultimoDia = DateFormat('EEEE').format(DateTime(fechaActual.year, fechaActual.month + 1, 0));
    indiceDelUltimoDia = FormatearFecha().obtenerIndiceDelDiaEnLaSemana(ultimoDia);
    getUltimoDiaMesAnterior();
  }

  Future<bool> registrar() async {
    bool flag = false;
    // Map<String, dynamic> json = {'nombre': nombre.text.toString()};
    Map<String, dynamic> json = {};
    if (!isEditing) {
      if (await asignacionHorarioService.put(json, usuarioId)) {
        if (_idBorrador.isNotEmpty) {
          BorradorService().delete(_idBorrador, 'AsignacionHorarios');
        }
        flag = true;
      }
    } else {
      if (await asignacionHorarioService.put(json, _idEditing)) {
        flag = true;
      }
    }
    if (flag) {
      clearForm();
    }

    return flag;
  }

  clearForm() {
    formKey.currentState!.reset();
    resetForm = true;
    isEditing = false;
    hayDatos = false;
    _idEditing = '';
    _idBorrador = '';

    usuarioId = '';
    usuarioNombre = '';
    nombreTipoJornada = '';
    idTipoJornada = '';
    tipoHorario = '';
    tipoHorarioBool = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  verHorarioDeUnDiaEspecifico(BuildContext context, diaAsignado, diaSemana, diaMesActual) async {
    String diaEscrito = FormatearFecha().obtenerNombreDiaSemana(diaSemana);
    if (diaAsignado['horario'][diaEscrito.toLowerCase()].isEmpty) return;

    final sMarcaciones = diaAsignado['horario'][diaEscrito.toLowerCase()].split(';');

    Map<String, dynamic> json = {
      'fecha': '$diaEscrito $diaMesActual de $mesEscrito del $anio',
      'entrada': FormatearFecha().minutosHaciaHoraHorarioAsignado(int.parse(sMarcaciones[0])),
      'colacion': FormatearFecha().minutosHaciaHoraHorarioAsignado(int.parse(sMarcaciones[1])),
      'fin_colacion': FormatearFecha().minutosHaciaHoraHorarioAsignado(int.parse(sMarcaciones[2])),
      'salida': FormatearFecha().minutosHaciaHoraHorarioAsignado(int.parse(sMarcaciones[3])),
      'entrada_2':
          sMarcaciones.length > 4 ? FormatearFecha().minutosHaciaHoraHorarioAsignado(int.parse(sMarcaciones[4])) : '',
      'colacion_2':
          sMarcaciones.length > 4 ? FormatearFecha().minutosHaciaHoraHorarioAsignado(int.parse(sMarcaciones[5])) : '',
      'fin_colacion_2':
          sMarcaciones.length > 4 ? FormatearFecha().minutosHaciaHoraHorarioAsignado(int.parse(sMarcaciones[6])) : '',
      'salida_2':
          sMarcaciones.length > 4 ? FormatearFecha().minutosHaciaHoraHorarioAsignado(int.parse(sMarcaciones[7])) : ''
    };

    await AsignacionDiaEspecificoDialog.showDia(context, json);
  }

  late Function _apiCallTipoJornada;
  set apiCallTipoJornada(Function function) {
    _apiCallTipoJornada = function;
  }

  // refrescar el dropdown de tipo de jornada con nuevos datos del mismo
  refrescarDropDownTipoJornada() {
    _apiCallTipoJornada();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share the code for `asignacionHorarioFormProvider` as well

Comment: Seems like ChangeNotifier is not that higher enough in the widget tree.

Comment: @Davis So there is no way for a provider to fulfill its function of refreshing itself in case there are changes within the same component?

Comment: That's possible! You need to use Streams if possible you could convert your data to streams then use streambuilder to update data if any new or update data is made